# Spring Security 6 and JSP view rendering

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm upgrading an application from Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3 which includes updating to Spring Security 6.

We have the following properties set:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

We use JSPs as a template language, where the controller returns the view file name e.g.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
  return "home";
}
```

This will render the JSP page `/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp`

The security config is e.g.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig  {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain config(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
          .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
      );

}
```

Since upgrading, visiting `localhost/` redirects the browser to `localhost/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp` and this returns a 403 because access to that page isn't permitted.

If I allow access to this with `.requestMatchers("/", "/WEB-INF/**").permitAll()` it works OK (i.e. stays on `/` and renders the JSP page) but this seems like a bad idea, and an unnecessary step.

With debug logging on, Spring logs the following:

```
DEBUG [requestURL=/] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
DEBUG [requestURL=/] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /
DEBUG [requestURL=/] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /WEB-INF/view/home.jsp
DEBUG [requestURL=/] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /WEB-INF/view/home.jsp
```

I cant' see anything in Spring Security migration guide about this, does anyone know what is going on?

## Update

I've isolated this into a clean example:

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsptest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jsptest</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    </project>
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain config(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/WEB-INF/view/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        return http.build();
    }

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

src/main/resources/application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp:

```
hello
```

Comment: `spring-boot` by default with executable as `jar` and container of `tomcat` or `jetty` or `undertow` does not support `jsp`. You must have some specific configurations made and made them work in spring-boot 2.7 so please share them as well as those need to be migrated as well

Comment: Your security configuration looks wrong. Which `init` method are you overriding? YOu should have a method that returns a `SecurityFilter` from the `HttpSecurity` method.

Comment: @M.Deinum have fixed the config, apologies it was extracted for this post from a `AbstractHttpConfigurer` class.

Comment: I still miss an `@EnableWebSecurity`... Nonetheless I doubt the security is your issue but not everything is in your question so it is hard to get to an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Something I've overlooked first as well.

In Spring Security 6, forwards and includes are part of the security filter by default.

See [Permit FORWARD when using Spring MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8.0/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_permit_forward_when_using_spring_mvc)

Allowing forwards globally can be done through this additional line in security configuration.

```java
.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
```

Comment: Note that there are two types of "DispatcherType" classes that your IDE might offer to import - the one you want is the jakarta.servlet.DispatcherType: NOT the Spring variant, which is a little counterintuitive :)