# Spring security 6.0 with JSP page has too many redirects with own login form

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, spring-security

I'm doing my project with adding login and register features. I follow the tutorial but I get there is too many redirects to this page:
My code in Controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginForm() {
        System.out.println(1);
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registrationForm(Model model) {
        UserDto user = new UserDto();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "register";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") UserDto userDto,
            BindingResult result,
            Model model) {
        User existingUser = userService.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail());

        if (existingUser != null)
            result.rejectValue("email", null,
                    "User already registered !!!");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("user", userDto);
            return "/registration";
        }

        userService.save(userDto);
        return "redirect:/registration?success";
    }
}
```

and SecurityConfig:

```
@Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/registration/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/")

                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll())
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
        return http.build();
    }
```

Did I do wrong something. Please help me.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: At what point does it redirect? The login, or the registration itself?

Please see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495244/too-many-redirects-with-own-login-form-spring-security

Or this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310634/spring-boot-too-many-redirects

Comment: How did you handle form errors? Also post your JSP page.

Comment: @JCompetence It redirect to the login page itself.

Comment: @RomanC I follow the tutorial here https://www.codeburps.com/post/spring-boot-form-login except that they use Thymeleaf. I change the template to JSP page.

Comment: Didn't you see something wrong in the tutorial. How do you handle validation errors?

Comment: @RomanC I'm so sorry, I don't know how I can handle validation errors. I will learn more about it. Fortunately, I just figure out the way to solve my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

According to the question I just found, [Spring Security 6 and JSP view rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75004603/spring-security-6-and-jsp-view-rendering)
I can solve my problem when I add  `dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()` to my SecurityConfig.

Comment: I spent hours trying to solve this problem after migrating from Spring Boot 2 to 3. @suyoung07's suggestion worked for me.

Note that there are two types of "DispatcherType" classes that your IDE might offer to import - the one you want is the jakarta.servlet.DispatcherType: NOT the Spring variant, which is slightly counterintuitive :)